# Error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Utils::chooseHandler() when using mediawiki extension "Discord-OAuth2Client"

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, mediawiki

- Extension link: https://github.com/t-mhi/MW-TMHI-Discord-OAuth2Client
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- MediaWiki version: 1.36.1
- PHP version: 7.3.29
- Composer version: 2.1.6

I installed this extension on my MediaWiki website.

I used
`git clone https://github.com/t-mhi/MW-TMHI-Discord-OAuth2Client.git` in extensions directory, and used `git submodule update --init` in MW-TMHI-Discord-OAuth2Client.

I checked file list

```
wiki@ubuntu:~/w/extensions/MW-TMHI-Discord-OAuth2Client/vendors/oauth2-client$ ls
CHANGELOG.md     CREDITS.md  README.PROVIDER-GUIDE.md  README.UPGRADING.md  composer.json  src
CONTRIBUTING.md  LICENSE     README.PROVIDERS.md       README.md            phpunit.xml    test
```

And I went to directory /w/extensions/MW-TMHI-Discord-OAuth2Client/vendors/oauth2-client and typed `composer install` command.

I modified LocalSettings.php as shown in https://github.com/t-mhi/MW-TMHI-Discord-OAuth2Client#usage

```
$wgOAuth2Client['client']['id']     = 'key'; // The client ID assigned to you by the provider
$wgOAuth2Client['client']['secret'] = 'key'; // The client secret assigned to you by the provider
$wgOAuth2Client['configuration']['redirect_uri'] = 'https://wikidomain/wiki/Special:OAuth2Client/callback'; // URL for OAuth2 server to redire>
$wgOAuth2Client['configuration']['scopes'] = 'identity'; // Permissions, refer to https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resourc>

$wgWhitelistRead = ['Main Page', 'Special:UserLogin', 'Special:OAuth2Client', 'Special:OAuth2Client/redirect', 'Request Wiki Access', 'Join T-MHI'];
$wgOAuth2Client['configuration']['service_login_link_text'] = 'Discord로 로그인'; // Korean message
```

Of course 'key' was entered as my Discord Developer App OAuth2 key.

I got an error (`$wgShowExceptionDetails = true;`):

```
/wiki/Special:OAuth2Client/redirect?returnto=Special:OAuth2Client/close Error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Utils::chooseHandler()

Backtrace:

from /home/wiki/w/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php(61)
#0 /home/wiki/w/extensions/MW-TMHI-Discord-OAuth2Client/vendors/oauth2-client/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php(42): GuzzleHttp\choose_handler()
#1 /home/wiki/w/extensions/MW-TMHI-Discord-OAuth2Client/vendors/oauth2-client/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(65): GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack::create()
#2 /home/wiki/w/extensions/MW-TMHI-Discord-OAuth2Client/vendors/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(131): GuzzleHttp\Client->__construct(array)
#3 /home/wiki/w/extensions/MW-TMHI-Discord-OAuth2Client/vendors/oauth2-client/src/Provider/GenericProvider.php(99): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->__construct(array, array)
#4 /home/wiki/w/extensions/MW-TMHI-Discord-OAuth2Client/SpecialOAuth2Client.php(60): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider->__construct(array)
#5 /home/wiki/w/vendor/wikimedia/object-factory/src/ObjectFactory.php(244): SpecialOAuth2Client->__construct()
#6 /home/wiki/w/vendor/wikimedia/object-factory/src/ObjectFactory.php(150): Wikimedia\ObjectFactory::getObjectFromSpec(array, array)
#7 /home/wiki/w/includes/specialpage/SpecialPageFactory.php(1215): Wikimedia\ObjectFactory->createObject(string, array)
#8 /home/wiki/w/includes/MediaWiki.php(268): MediaWiki\SpecialPage\SpecialPageFactory->getPage(string)
#9 /home/wiki/w/includes/MediaWiki.php(913): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#10 /home/wiki/w/includes/MediaWiki.php(546): MediaWiki->main()
#11 /home/wiki/w/index.php(53): MediaWiki->run()
#12 /home/wiki/w/index.php(46): wfIndexMain()
#13 {main}
```

**~/w/extensions/MW-TMHI-Discord-OAuth2Client/vendors/oauth2-client/composer.json**:

```
{
    "name": "league/oauth2-client",
    "description": "OAuth 2.0 Client Library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.0",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ircmaxell/random-lib": "~1.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "~0.9",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~2.0",
        "satooshi/php-coveralls": "0.6.*",
        "jakub-onderka/php-parallel-lint": "0.8.*"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "oauth",
        "oauth2",
        "authorization",
        "authentication",
        "idp",
        "identity",
        "sso",
        "single sign on"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Alex Bilbie",
            "email": "hello@alexbilbie.com",
            "homepage": "http://www.alexbilbie.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "League\\OAuth2\\Client\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "League\\OAuth2\\Client\\Test\\": "test/src/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0.x-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Which version of `guzzlehttp/guzzle` did you install in the end?

Comment: I have no knowledge of composer and don't know which one to try.  It is as above.